# ajax not completing process due to table locking

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 quires which i am implementing in ajax

the first insert.php insert thousand record in database
the second update.php gets the num of inserted records every 10 milliseconds.

when i make a call to insert.php the insertion in table starts. but when update.php also starts to run i don't get any output from update.php until insert.php has completed its operation.

i am using mysql and storage engine is Innob

individually both the functions work perfectly.

can anyone explain what problem there is. What i can think of is that there is a table locking issue.

your suggestions are most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you test it on your computer or on a server?

Comment: i think it could be a performance issue. you could test it on a powerful webserver and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: are you using an transactions for the insert? the update.php only does an select/only read access, right? so i don't think of an performance issue, because the the update.php runs reproducible after the insert.php

Comment: it's not about performance. The insert on innodb requires exclusive lock.

Answer (score 1):

Please read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

INSERT sets an exclusive lock. The update is trying also a lock, but as the manual says: "lock cannot be granted immediately" no matter if the update wants a shared or exclusive lock.